# How to swap array element in bash shell linux?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I have a problem regarding about the syntax on how to swap the element value in an array.

```
array="5 3 2 1 4"
echo "${array[*]}"

changed=1
while [ $changed != 0 ]
do
    changed=0
    for (( i=0 ; i<=${#array[@]}-1 ; i++ )) 
    do
        if [ ${array[$i]} -gt ${array[$i+1]} ]
            then
                tmp=${array[$i]}
                array[$i]=${array[$i+1]}
                array[$i+1]=$tmp
                changed=1
        fi
    done    
done

echo "Sorted array: "
echo "${array[*]}"
```

Edit:

Thanks for answering my question. I have changed the code, and now and it looks something like this.

But unfortunately there is still a problem.

It says:

```
jdoodle.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found
jdoodle.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
jdoodle.sh: line 8: `    for ((i=0;i<=${#array[@]}-1;i++))
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: For arithmetic within a shell `((...integer math...))` is the preferred method, `$((...integer math...))` for the result itself (`let` and `expr` work, but have limitations by comparison). Note: `for (( i=0 ; i<${#array[@]}; i++ ))` and for indexed arrays `${array[i]}` is sufficient in bash. But for arithmetic within the index `$((i+1))` is the best choice.

Comment: No spaces around `=` in assignments.

Comment: Thanks for answering guys, yes, i have just removed the unnecessary space. but I am now facing now about for loop process. :( any suggestion.. Thank You.

Comment: Are you using a WIndows editor? Windows uses cr lf (`\r\n`) as end of line; Linux and Unix use only `\n`. See `man dos2unix`.

Comment: Hi. @LjmDullaart I am using online compiler. here: https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online

Comment: On a different note, there is little practical benefit to implementing a sorting routine in shell. Arrays aren't meant to implement data structures; they are meant to act as a second layer of quoting to allow storing lists of arguments. You would be better off learning things like how to properly quote parameter expansions than implementing algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

This is one implementation of bubble sort:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(5 3 2 1 4)
echo "${array[*]}"

size=${#array[@]}

for (( i=0; i<size-1; i++ )); do

   for (( j=0; j<size-i-1; j++ )); do
      if (( array[j] > array[j+1] )); then
         tmp=${array[j]}
         array[j]=${array[j+1]}
         array[j+1]=$tmp
      fi
   done

done

echo "Sorted array:"
echo "${array[*]}"
```

---

Major problem with your code is that it actually **does not** use arrays.

Define arrays like `array=(value1 value2 value3)`. It's also better to use `[[ ]]` for testing instead of `[ ]`. If we were to change your code just a little to also create a functioning bubble sort algorithm, it could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(5 3 2 1 4)
echo "${array[*]}"

changed=1 j=0

while [[ $changed != 0 ]]
do
    ((j++))
    changed=0
    for (( i=0; i<${#array[@]}-j; i++ )) 
    do  
        if [[ ${array[i]} -gt ${array[i+1]} ]]
        then
           tmp=${array[i]}
           array[i]=${array[i+1]}
           array[i+1]=$tmp
           changed=1
        fi  
    done        
done

echo "Sorted array:"
echo "${array[*]}"
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for suggestion. I've tried to compile it online using https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online

Comment: @J.John why do you test it using online interpreter?

Comment: Hi @PesaThe, because I don't have linux installed in my laptop. :)

Comment: @J.John The code should work, try some other online tool, for example [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php) looks very good

Comment: @J.John, you can get busybox, no installation needed.

Comment: @J.John MacOS has bash; on Windows you can install Cygwin and you will have everything you need

Answer (score 0):

I do not get the \r messages, even in your test environment; in general, they are a result of DOS/Windows combatability (with a b).

Since this is obviously a tutorial example (why else would someone do bubblesort), some remarks about the code.

```
array="5 3 2 1 4"
```

does not create the array that you want. It creates a string. What you are looking for is:

```
array=(5 3 2 1 4)
```

The last element of the array is `${#array[@]}-1`. Element counting starts at 0. So your for-loop should be:

```
for (( i=0 ; i<=${#array[@]}-2 ; i++ ))
```

`-2` because you're referencing `${array[$i+1]}`, which would otherwise be outside the boundary.